# SAS Proc GLM Predicted Output

Tags: sas, prediction

I'm using SAS Proc GLM to make predictions for a dependent variable with some missing values. Note that all of the predictor variables are fully observed, i.e., the predictors contain no missing values. The standard syntax is:

> proc glm data=test;
>
> class a;
>
> model dv=a b c/solution;
>
> output out=testx p=pred;
>
> run;

Since the predictors have no missing values the output data should contain predictions for the missing values wrt the dependent variable.

My output does not contain predictions for the missing values in the dependent variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Post the log and the output from proc contents on the textX data set. The answer likely likes in those two sections.

Comment: @reeza  thanks for your comment. The log is clean and shows no errors. The predictors have been scrutinized for possible MVs that would cancel predictions.

Comment: Well if you won't provide any more information besides what you've posted we have no way to verify what you're saying. There may not be errors but there may be warnings that indicate what's happening and it could be data specfic. Without a replicable set of data there's nothing else to offer.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to show your work.  This example contradicts your claim.

```
data class;
   set sashelp.class;
   x = ranuni(1);
   if x gt .9 then weight=.;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc glm;
   class sex; 
   model weight=sex height age / solution; 
   output out=testx p=pred r=r;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. As a long-time SAS user I'm aware of the contradiction. That's why I'm puzzled by the problem.